# Unable to pick date from <input type="date" > with keyboard input disabled in Protractor

Tags: angular, date, protractor

I have input from keyboard disabled for a date picker.

```html
<input _ngcontent-c6="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine 
    ng-invalid" formcontrolname="attractionDate" id="eventdate" 
    *onkeydown="return false"** placeholder="Enter Your Event" 
    type="date" ng-reflect-name="attractionDate" min="2018-03-20">
```

I have tried sending keys using:
`productRegistration.attractionDate.sendKeys('07/07/2018');`

It is not sending any key nor is generating any error. I have tried all solutions, but none of them click on the UI of the date. Please help!

Image of the calender:
[image: Need to click down triangle to set date]

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular? Given the `_ngcontent-6` attribute I'm guessing Angular. Please remove the angularjs tag if that is the case.

Comment: @DavidWalschots Yes I am using Angular2, I have removed the tag

Comment: I'm assuming protractor being a testing framework is simulating the user. Therefore, it probably can't set keyboard input on a disabled field.

Comment: @DavidWalschots Is there a work-around to click on the down arrow and have mouse events to select a date?

Comment: I'm not a protractor user. Do you want to test this specific control, or do you want to fill in a form so you can submit and continue? If the latter, then I'd simply set the value of the date control programmatically. Note that the programmatic value of a date input is different from the presentation format, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format/9519493#9519493).